# How to improve solve error in motion tracking with low-contrast footage?

Tags: objects, tracking, motion-capture

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z6sRF_rNefpGxr_3B1EoVM0mLPrdfLY3/view?usp=sharing
^^ image sequence in question. Blender file is almost not useful.

For my first motion tracking project, I probably couldn't have picked a worse piece of footage. It's cellphone footage - finding the right sensor width and focal length for the Pixel 7 has proven nearly impossible. There are very few contrasty bits; the perspective changes wildly; the few contrasty bits tend to leave the screen, and most of the usable contrasty bits are located all in the center. My solve error is really hard to get down.

I'm currently using an Affine tracker for everything. I really don't know what I can do to make this better. I am trying to use as many dirt bits on the table as possible. I'm not really sure what qualifies as a good "feature" to track. I've been at this for hours.

Any thoughts/tips? Not looking for anyone to make markers, but things like "for the blue caps, use perspective, because X"